# How to dynamically create <li> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Please check the below JavaScript code

```
<script>
            function dynamicMessageLoader(id) {

                $.get("SentMessagesDynamicLoaderServlet?idMessageGroup=" + id, function (responseJson) {

                    $('#li_list').empty();
                    var array = [];

                    $.each(responseJson, function (index, item)

                    {
                        array[index] = item;
                    });

                    $('#message_count').empty();

                    var readArray = array.length;

                    var count = readArray + " Messages Selected";

                    $('<p />', {html: count}).appendTo('#message_count');

                    for (var i = 0; i < readArray; i++) {

                        $('<li />', {html: array[i][0]}).appendTo('#li_list');

                    }
                });
            }
  </script>
```

Then some HTML

```
<ul id="li_list"></ul>
```

In my JavaScript code, consider this section -

```
 `$('<li />', {html: array[i][0]}).appendTo('#li_list');`
```

What I want is not to just create a `<li>` but with its remaining attributes, exactly like below

```
<li class='clickable-row hand' id="3" >Text here</li>
```

In my array, `array[i][0]` contains the ID and `array[i][1]` contains a text. How can I achieve this?

Comment: And the problem is? Create the `li`, add the classes (`.addClass()`), add the id (`.attr()`), add the text (`.text()`/`.html()`) and append to the list (`.appendTo()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be `$('<li>', {html: array[i][1], 'class': 'clickable-row hand', id: array[i][0]})`

Please note, that attributes may be without quotes, except `class` that is reserved word.

---

*Alternative*

```
var li = $('<li>');
li
    .addClass('clickable-row hand')
    .text(array[i][1])
    .attr('id', array[i][0])
    .appendTo('#li_list')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on correct path,

```
$('<li />', {
     "id": array[i][0], 
     "text" : array[i][1],
     "class" : 'clickable-row hand'
}).appendTo('#li_list');
```

OR, Create a object then use various method to manipulate element.

```
var li = $('<li />');
li.attr("id", array[i][0]);
li.text(array[i][1]);
li.addClass("id", 'clickable-row hand');
li.appendTo('#li_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this. create li and add attr & text to it and append that li to `#li_list`

```
for (var i = 0; i < readArray; i++) {

     var li = $('<li/>')
            .attr('id', array[i][0])
            .text(array[i][1]);
            .addClass('clickable-row hand');

     $("#li_list").append(li);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) +1 from me